# can i highlight any text using Javascript other than the textarea and input text element?

Tags: javascript

using Javascript, it is easy to programatically select the text inside a textarea or input text element.  How about for

```
<span>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span>
```

is it possible to use JavaScript to select the words "quick brown fox"?  Or select the whole sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Courtesy of http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=459934

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fnSelect(objId) {
        fnDeSelect();
        if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(objId));
        range.select();
        }
        else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById(objId));
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        }
    }

    function fnDeSelect() {
        if (document.selection) document.selection.empty(); 
        else if (window.getSelection)
                window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
    </script>
<body>

<div id="test1">
    <p>jhsdgfhlsdlfkjsdklgjs</p>
    <p>jhsdgfhlsdlfkjsdklgjs</p>
    <p>jhsdgfhlsdlfkjsdklgjs</p>
</div>
<div id="test2">
    <p>jhsdgfhlsdlfkjsdklgjs</p>
    <p>jhsdgfhlsdlfkjsdklgjs</p>
    <p>jhsdgfhlsdlfkjsdklgjs</p>
</div>
<a href="javascript:fnSelect('test1');">Select 1</a>
<a href="javascript:fnSelect('test2');">Select 2</a>
<a href="javascript:fnDeSelect();">DeSelect</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Had to try it. Worked perfectly. +1

Answer (score 1):

You will need some way to manipulate the `span` tag. Such as an `id`, but then in javascript I would edit some of the `style` properties. You could have a property for everything you want to highlight like what is shown below.

```
.HL {
    background: #ffff99; 
    color: #000000;
}
```

If you do that then you will need to get a reference to the specific tag.

```
DocumentgetElementsByTagName("title")
```

Otherwise `Document.getElementByID("ID")` is good for unique ids.
Then using `setAttribute(name, value)` To change the class to the one given.

This is just a simple example but there are many ways to do this.

```
<span id="abc" class=""> Sample </span>
var temp = Document.getelementByID("abc");
temp.setAttribute('class', 'HL');
```

Answer (score 0):

in css you could create a .highlight class

```
.highlight{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

in javascript you could add the .highlight class to the elements you wish to highlight

```
<getSpanElement>.className='highlight';
```

this text is then highlighted, though it is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight or select? I think you actually want to select not to highlight.

Highlight... yes! Set the proper CSS properties of the `span` element, for instance foreground and background color.

Edit: That is called selecting. Sorry, I don't know of any way to do it.

Comment: coz when i say "selecting", some users thought it meant "getting the  value of".